# Fixar menu ao topo da página quando rolar para baixo

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Tenho uma div com  **height 100%** e após ela uma **navbar**. Gostaria de que, quando descesse a página a navbar se fixasse ao topo da página.

**CSS**

```
ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #27ae60;
    text-align:center;
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
}
ul.navbar li {
    display: inline;
}
ul.navbar li:not(:nth-last-child(2)) {
    border-right: 1px solid #079342;
}
ul.navbar li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
    -moz-transition-duration: .3s;
    -o-transition-duration: .3s;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
}
ul.navbar li a:hover { 
    color: #e6e6e6 !important;
}
ul.navbar li.navbar-icon {display: none;}
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.navbar{text-align:left;}
  ul.navbar li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  ul.navbar li.navbar-icon {
    float: right;
    padding-bottom: -5px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  ul.navbar li.navbar-icon a {
    padding-bottom: 17px;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
    ul.navbar.navbar-responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.navbar.navbar-responsive li.navbar-icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    ul.navbar.navbar-responsive li {
        float: none;
        display: inline;
    }
    ul.navbar.navbar-responsive li a {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }
    ul.navbar li:first-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="navbar-icon">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" onclick="menuToggle()"><i class="ion-navicon"></i></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ve se isso lhe ajuda, ai muda as propriedades para em vex de mudar a a cor, mudar a posiçao para fixed. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178407/efeito-menu-aparecer-lentamente-css/178419#178419

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo bacana, costumo usar este.
Simples e fácil implementação
algo mais complexo, tu vai precisar js mais avançado
https://codepen.io/senff/pen/ayGvD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja funcionando aqui [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49qtth99/3/).

Usa a função `scroll`, detecta o evento de rolar a página, verifica se o tamanho rolado para baixo é maior a altura da `navbar`. Se maior, adiciona a classe que força ele ficar no topo - se não, remove a classe caso tenha sido atribuída alguma vez.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 60)
        {
            $('#navbar').addClass('navbar-fixed-top', 500);
        } else {
            $('#navbar').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top', 500);  
        }
    });
});
```

Aqui o `CSS`, com a classe mencionada no trecho acima. A classe força a posição ser fixa no topo e o tamanho na horizontal ser extender a 100%.

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou bem, porém ela fixa quando passam os primeiros 60 pixels, preciso que fixe ao passar de 100% da altura

Comment: Troque `60px` por `screen.height` que é o tamanho em 100% do tela.